# Is it possible to read from and write to the same text file in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, streamreader, streamwriter

Here is the situation.  I have over 1500 SQL (text) files that contain a "GRANT some privilege ON some table TO some user after the CREATE TABLE statement.  I need to remove them from the original file and put the GRANT statements in their own file.  Sometimes the Grants are on a single line and sometimes they are split across multiple lines.  For example:

```
  GRANT SELECT ON XYZ.TABLE1 TO MYROLE1 ;
  GRANT
  SELECT ON XYZ.TABLE1 TO MYROLE2 ;
  GRANT
  DELETE,
  INSERT,
  SELECT,
  UPDATE ON XYZ.TABLE1 TO MYROLE3;
```

I am reading through the file until I get to the GRANT and then building a string containing the text from the GRANT to the semicolon which I then write out to another file.  I have an app I wrote in Delphi (Pascal) and this part works great.  What I would like to do is after I read and have processed the line I want, I would like to delete the line from the original text file.  I can't do this in the Delphi.  The only solution there is to read the file line by line and write the file back out to another file excluding the lines I don't want while also writing the GRANTS to yet another file. Then delete the original and rename the new. Way too much processing and risk.

I looked at using the StreamReader and StreamWriter in C# but it appears to be similar situation to Delphi.  I can Read or I can Write but I can't do both to the same file at the same time.

I would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations.

Thanks

Comment: File.ReadAllText and then a File.WriteAllText. no need to keep the file open while processing for short files like this.

Comment: Did you try the `FileStream` class?

Comment: There's not really a good way to do it. Varying length records are tough to deal with in most filesystems. Sounds like a nice class that abstracts text files of lines to a `List`, though, like `DataTable` / `DataContext`.

Comment: How sure are you about your claim that you can't do this in Delphi? I highly doubt it lacks the capability. Just might need to use a little extra WinAPI calls at worst.

Comment: "*The only solution there is to read the file line by line and write the file back out to another file excluding the lines I don't want while also writing the GRANTS to yet another file. Then delete the original and rename the new*" - that is the only way you CAN do it, safely, in any programming language. There is simply no (easy) way to delete arbitrary data from the front or middle of an open file. Saving the wanted data to a separate file is the best way, in Delphi or in C#. Otherwise, like Ron said, just read the whole file into memory, modify the data as needed, and write it back out.

Comment: "*Sounds like a nice class that abstracts text files of lines to a `List`*" - in Delphi, the `TStringList` is the one to use for that

Comment: @Jerry Delphi isn't special. This can't be done at all. No language can perform the impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think there's "way too much processing and risk" in *generating the a new temporary file without the lines you don't want and replacing the original*: then consider the alternative you're hoping to achieve.

```
    Line 1
    Line 2
    Delete this line
+-->Line 4
|   Line 5
|
+- Read position marker after reading line to be deleted
```

If you immediately delete the line while reading, the later lines have to be moved back into the "empty space" left behind after the 3rd line is deleted. In order to ensure you next read "Line 4", you'd have to *backtrack* your read-position-marker. What's the correct amount to backtrack? A "line" of *variable length*, or the *number of characters* of the deleted line?

**What you perceive to be the "risky" option is actually the *safe* option!**

---

If you want to delete while processing you can use an abstraction that gives you that impression. But you lose the benefits of stream processing and don't *really* eliminate any of the risk you were worried about in the first place.

E.g. Load your entire file into a list of strings; such as an array, vector or `TStringList` (in Delphi). Iterate the list and delete the items you don't want. Finally save the list back to file.

This approach has the following disadvantages:

- Potential high memory overhead because you load the entire file instead of small buffer for the stream.
- You're at risk of mid-process failure with no recovery, because your job is *all-or-nothing*.
- You have to deal with the nuances of the particular container you choose to hold your list of strings.

  - In some cases (e.g. `TStringList`) you might still need to backtrack your position marker in a similar fashion to the earlier description.
  - For arrays you'd have to copy all lines back 1 position every time you delete something with a huge performance cost. (The same happens in `TStringList` though it's hidden from you.)
  - Iterators for some containers are invalidated whenever you modify the list. This means you'd have to copy to a new list without the 'deleted lines' in any case. *More memory overhead.*

In conclusion, take the ***safe option***. Use a separate read and write stream; write to a temporary file, and rename when done. *It will save you headaches.*

Comment: You can perfectly well have a read stream and a write stream to avoid high memory load

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You've misread. I never claimed otherwise. In fact I pointed out that a **disadvantage of loading the entire file** into memory is high memory load: "***instead of small buffer for the stream***". Converse to the disadvantage of a load file approach is the stream based approach which has the **advantage** of _not requiring a high memory footprint_.

Comment: I can't see any advantage to loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you bothering to read the answer at all? The only objective is to produce to an abstraction that would allow OP to process the file in the manner asked in the question. I also don't see any advantage to loading the entire file into memory; which is precisely why I haven't listed any; I've only listed **disadvantages** to it. And if OP sees reason, he won't continue pursuing his idea.

Comment: I have to say I struggled following the answer.